# multiple views are not working in ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please helpme why i'm not able to display mutipul view in Another html page.But it display in Index.html Page(Page is redirecting to another page but it lose its views)

**Index.html**

```
    <a ui-sref="MultiView">MultiView</a>
```

**MyApp.Js**

```
 .state('MultiView', {
        url: '/MultiViewGenerated',
        views: {
            'Employee': {
                templateUrl: '/ApiClient/MultiView/MultiView.html',
                controller: 'MultiCtrls',

            },
            'Department': {
                 template:'Hello',
            }
```

**Htmlcode**

Here Employee Working fine but why `Department`  is not working

```
 <div ng-controller="MultiCtrls">
        <p>This is MultiView</p>

    </div>

    <div ui-view="Employee">

    </div>
<hr />

    <div ui-view="Department">
        <p>This is MultiView2...</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error is not showing but  ui-view="Department"  is not displaying anything

Comment: Both (Employee And Department) r in same page MultiView.html